How to convert an incidence matrix, of a bipartite network, to an unipartite projection
I would like to convert an incidence matrix of a bipartite procjection into a matrix of an unipartite projection.
For example:
I have this matrix, in which the columns are interacting with the respective rows when element equals > 0.
int <- matrix(rbinom(48, 5, 0.2),nrow=8,ncol=6)
colnames(int) <- letters[1:6]
rownames(int) <- letters[7:14]

I would like to generate a adjacency (square matrix) of the higher nodes (the columns), in which the new elements will be the at least number they shared interaction with the same rows (g to n, for example).
So if my int matrix is this one:
  a b c d e f
g 1 0 0 1 0 1
h 1 0 2 1 1 1
i 1 1 1 0 0 2
j 1 2 0 1 0 1
k 1 1 3 0 2 1
l 1 1 2 3 1 0
m 3 2 2 1 0 1
n 2 1 0 1 1 0

My unipartite projection resulting will be like:
   a  b  c  d  e f
a  0  7  6  6
b     0  5
c        0
d           0
e              0   
f                 0

In which, for example the pairs ab shared interaction with six rows and the number will be the at least x numbers shared 1+1+1+1+2+1, which refers to interactions with the shared interactions with i, j, k, l, m and n.
Any ideas on how to perform this, please?

`diag<-`(crossprod(df>0), 0)

  a b c d e f
a 0 2 3 3 3 0
b 2 0 2 1 1 0
c 3 2 0 3 2 0
d 3 1 3 0 3 0
e 3 1 2 3 0 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 0


it worked perfectly! Thank you!! The part diag<- and the zero in the end it's only assignign the diagonal as zero, right?

@Pam yes. thats correct

With igraph:
bg <- graph_from_biadjacency_matrix(int, multiple=T)
ug <- bipartite_projection(bg)$proj2

The multiplicities are saved in the weight edge attribute.

Update 2
If you want to save the words, you can try
l <- asplit(int, 2)
`diag<-`(outer(l, l, FUN = Vectorize(\(x, y) sum(pmin(x, y)))), 0)

or
l <- asplit(int, 2)
as.dist(outer(l, l, FUN = Vectorize(\(x, y) sum(pmin(x, y)))), TRUE, TRUE)

and both of them can produce
  a b c d e f
a 0 7 6 6 4 6
b 7 0 5 4 3 4
c 6 5 0 4 4 4
d 6 4 4 0 3 4
e 4 3 4 3 0 2
f 6 4 4 4 2 0


Update 1
As per the changes in the questions, you can try the code below without igraph
v <- combn(asplit(int, 2), 2, \(...) sum(do.call(pmin, ...)))
m <- matrix(0, ncol(int), ncol(int), dimnames = rep(list(colnames(int)), 2))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- v
m <- pmax(m, t(m))

and you will obtain
> m
  a b c d e f
a 0 7 6 6 4 6
b 7 0 5 4 3 4
c 6 5 0 4 4 4
d 6 4 4 0 3 4
e 4 3 4 3 0 2
f 6 4 4 4 2 0

Data
> dput(int)
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 1L, 0L), dim = c(8L, 6L), dimnames = list(c("g", "h", "i",
"j", "k", "l", "m", "n"), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")))


First Answer
Below is just a completion of @Szabolcs igraph answer, if you would like to solve the problem in an igraph way
int %>%
  graph_from_biadjacency_matrix(multiple = TRUE) %>%
  bipartite_projection() %>%
  pluck("proj2") %>%
  as_adjacency_matrix(attr = "weight", sparse = FALSE)

and you will obtain
  a b c d e f
a 0 2 2 0 2 1
b 2 0 2 1 2 0
c 2 2 0 1 3 3
d 0 1 1 0 1 0
e 2 2 3 1 0 1
f 1 0 3 0 1 0


thank you! At first, I thought it had worked, but the sums do not add up. I edited my question to try to explain better what I need. I need the minimum number of shared interactions, so if a and b interacted with m 3 and 2 times (respectively), only the 2 would be included in the sum for this pair of nodes. And so on for the other interactions.

@Pam see my update
